# noSuchMethodError when starting spring boot application with eureka

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud, netflix-eureka, nosuchmethoderror

When I start My Spring Boot Application with Eureka Server, I run into a **NoSuchMethodError**.
I tried the solutions of several similar questions from here, but sadly none of them worked in my case.

The Application worked like a charm before I decided to turn it into a cloud application by adding Eureka Server.

**My stacktrace:**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(java.lang.Object[])'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/ruthh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-cloud-context-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/BootstrapApplicationListener.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/ruthh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.6.3/spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder: file:/C:/Users/ruthh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.6.3/spring-boot-2.6.3.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener and org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
```

**My Application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/woerdl
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=[redacted]
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.sql.init.mode=always
server.port=8010

spring.application.name=woerdl_db
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=true
eureka.server.waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty=0
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds= 15
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds= 5
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

**My Main class:**

```
package de.derandy.woerdl_db;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

import de.derandy.woerdl_db.config.Config;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Woerdl_dbApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Config.config(args);

    }

}
```

**My Config class:**

```
package de.derandy.woerdl_db.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import de.derandy.woerdl_db.Woerdl_dbApplication;
import de.derandy.woerdl_db.wort.service.impl.WortServiceImpl;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    
    public static ApplicationContext context;

    public static Environment environment;
    
    public static String[] args;
    
    public static String random;
    
    @Autowired 
    private static WortServiceImpl wortService;
    
    public static void config(final String[] args) {
        Config.args = args;
        Config.context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Woerdl_dbApplication.class).registerShutdownHook(true)
                .run(Config.args);

        environment = Config.context.getEnvironment();
        
        wortService =   (WortServiceImpl) Config.context.getBean("wortServiceImpl");
        
        random = wortService.findRandom();
    }

}
```

**My pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.derandy</groupId>
    <artifactId>woerdl_db</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>woerdl_db</name>
    <description>Ein Wortspiel</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>17</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by editing the Pom.
I added **jaxb-runtime** and **spring-cloud-dependencies**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.derandy</groupId>
    <artifactId>woerdl_db</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>woerdl_db</name>
    <description>Ein Wortspiel</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>17</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```